# What services are available for person to person payment inside mobile app?

Tags: rest, payment

Im looking for a list of available services with rest api to implement person to person payments inside mobile app.

Here is few apps that uses such systems. Do anybody know what payment services they are using?

1. Uber - uber.com
2. Hailocab - hailocab.com
3. Airbnb - airbnb.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AirBnb - https://www.braintreepayments.com
Uber - http://www.authorize.net/. team is going to migrate to https://www.braintreepayments.com
Hailo - unknown =)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what providers they are using specifically but you could use Paypal for this purpose. Check out the Adaptive Payment API https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/adaptive-payments

I am not aware of any other providers that will let you do person to person payment, but there are of course a bunch of companies doing in App billing.

Comment: Adaptive Payment looks perfect for my case in an app i am developing. Well the only problem it would have is to always ask end user to give paypal email address to initiate translation?